# Use Powershell to read XML comments

Tags: windows-7, powershell, scheduled-task

So I'm working on a way to use Powershell to get a list of scheduled tasks. Through my research, I determined that the only way to get "most" tasks is to use SCHTASKS. This command does allow for XML output which you can push right into a variable:

```
$tasks = [xml](SCHTASKS /QUERY /XML ONE)
```

Now, the problem comes up is that the task name is stored as an XML comment. When added to tasks object, all of this data is stored under the "#comment" key. Using normal addressing rules, you would be accessing:

```
$tasks.Tasks.#comment
```

The above doesn't work of course because the number sign is a special character for comments so it ignores it. I can't escape the character with a back tick "`" so I am at a loss of what to do. I'd rather avoid having to do all of this through a csv file since I loose a lot of data when I do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
$tasks.Tasks.'#comment'
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Sorry for the delay on accepting it.